# MTLBuffer containing array of int2 has incorrect values when read by compute shader

Tags: ios, swift, buffer, gpu, metal

I am attempting to pass a buffer with an array of `int2` to a kernel function, using the following class:

```
class MetalHelper {    
    lazy var device: MTLDevice! = { MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() }()
    lazy var defaultLibrary: MTLLibrary! = { self.device.newDefaultLibrary() }()
    lazy var commandQueue: MTLCommandQueue! = { return self.device.newCommandQueue() }()
    var pipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!

    var inTexture: MTLTexture!
    var outTexture: MTLTexture!
    var testBuffer: [int2] = [int2(Int32(3), Int32(-1)), int2(Int32(0), Int32(7)), int2(Int32(2), Int32(-10))] // etc...

    // Additional setup of in and out textures, pipeline state....

    func compute() {
        commandQueue.insertDebugCaptureBoundary()

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.computeCommandEncoder()

        commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipelineState)
        commandEncoder.setTexture(inTexture, atIndex: 0)
        commandEncoder.setTexture(outTexture, atIndex: 1)

        let buffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(&testBuffer, length: sizeof(int2) * testBuffer.count, options: [.StorageModeShared])
        commandEncoder.setBuffer(buffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)

        let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSizeMake(16, 16, 1);
        let width = Int(inTexture.width / threadsPerThreadgroup.width)
        let height = Int(inTexture.height / threadsPerThreadgroup.height)
        let threadgroupCount = MTLSizeMake(width, height, 1)

        commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupCount, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
        commandEncoder.endEncoding()

        commandBuffer.commit()
        commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

        commandQueue.insertDebugCaptureBoundary()
    }
}
```

And in my shader function, read the values out of the buffer to get the color at a pixel. The buffer array length is known to be equal to the number of slices in `inTexture`.

```
kernel void average(texture2d_array<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
                     texture2d<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
                     const device int2 *testBuffer [[buffer(0)]],
                     uint2 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    uint total = inTexture.get_array_size();

    uint index;
    float4 averageColor = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (index = 0; index < total; index++) {
        int2 offset = testBuffer[index];
        const uint2 coordinate = uint2(gid.x + offset[0], gid.y + offset[1]);

        const float4 colorAtPixel = inTexture.read(coordinate, index);
        averageColor += colorAtPixel;
    }

    averageColor = averageColor / total;
    outTexture.write(averageColor, gid);
}
```

For some reason, the values in `testBuffer` are incorrect. Here is the GPU Frame:

[gputrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnxYj.png)

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you also show how you defined the offsetArray inside the .metal file?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. Updated now.

Comment: the problem might stem from the fact that you are creating "buffer" multiple times, on every call. that line should not be inside your loop function.

Comment: `testBuffer` is an array of `int2`, so the loop is attempting to index in and get each `int2` individually.